# Can you set xgboost global verbosity level at the R package?

Tags: r, xgboost

I'm looking for a way to silence xgboost warning produced c/cpp source code to R console. I was thinking of doing it by using the verbosity level on a global level as I can see there is a _global_verbosity level in the source. Searching for an exposed function to modify it yielded no results.

Am I missing an existing way to do it or it needs to be exposed?

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/184e2eac7dd7b1df324ab5c7fca32c810981fd8b/R-package/src/xgboost_custom.cc#L19

Answer (score 0):

It will be resolved with https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/pull/6414.

Global configurations will now be propagated to workers accordingly.